# Why is this string empty after having been modified by a function?

Tags: php, scope

So I'm just trying to replace spaces with dashes in a string like this:

```
    $string = "Some string with spaces";
```

The output should be Some-string-with-spaces

The function below does that, but trying to access the variable after the function, it's blank as if it wasn't changed.

```
$url_title_piece = "";

  function spaceDashReplace($string, $url_title_piece) {
    $string_length = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
      if ($string[$i] === " ") {
        $url_title_piece = $url_title_piece . "-";
      }
      else {
        $url_title_piece = $url_title_piece . $string[$i];
      }
    }
  }

  spaceDashReplace($string, $url_title_piece);
  echo 'modified string ' . $url_title_piece; // outputs modified string not modified string Some-string-with-spaces
```

I am able to get what I want if at the end of the for loop I return the modified $string.

I work with both JavaScript and PHP so I mix up things like I guess you don't have closure with PHP unlike JavaScript.

Edit: I also realize I should probably use some kind of string replace instead of doing this.

Comment: @Perumal93 that's okay to do? I was looking at that and saw something about using globals being bad, at any rate thanks.

Comment: use return in the function; your right global is bad. demo: http://ideone.com/R0NgRb

Comment: Just an FYI, everything in JS is in the global scope by default. In PHP it's not and, in this case, [PHP is better: global should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables/2496/global-variable-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks guys for the demo/links